# Getting values from string

Tags: java, xml, regex, string

I have string value, in that I need to get only text without comma or semicolon as like below example input:

```
<LINE>002:OR,004:0001,002:01,007:SCEM_02,000:, 002:PC;/</LINE>
```

My output should be like:

```
OR 0001 01 SCEM_02 PC
```

(I.e.) without any comma, semicolon, colon.

For this what function I need to use for it? Waiting for your reply.

Regards,
Joy

Comment: Where's your code? What language is this?

Comment: What language/platform do you use to parse xml?

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression
In python it would have been

```
import re
re.findall(r'.*(:[\w]+,?)+', "<LINE>002:OR,004:0001,002:01,007:SCEM_02,000:, 002:PC;/</LINE> ");
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: I need the solution in JAVA language

Comment: Well try tagging your question with `java` next time

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a one-liner:

```
input.replaceAll("(^|,|;).*?(:(?!,)|$)", " ").trim();
```

It's a matter of getting the regex right. This regex basically replaces with a space "everything between a comma/semi-colon and a colon, factoring in start/end issues"

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    String input = "<LINE>002:OR,004:0001,002:01,007:SCEM_02,000:, 002:PC;/</LINE>";
    input = input.replaceAll("(^|,|;).*?(:(?!,)|$)", " ").trim();
    System.out.println( input);
}
```

Output:

```
OR 0001 01 SCEM_02 PC
```